# making a delete request to URL rather than ID in a rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

i'm wondering if anyone can give me any advice.

I'm currently writing a rails API and although it doesn't seem like a best practice, rather than performing a DELETE call to

```
localhost:3000/products/:id
```

id rather make it to

```
localhost:3000/products/:url
```

and pass in the URL to be deleted, however i've currently got this but I keep getting a routing error.

```
DELETE '/products/:url', to: 'products#destroy'
```

is my current route for this, it is also specified above my

```
resources :products
```

sections.

My whole routes file:

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do      
  resources :features do
  resources :feature_links
  end

  resources :wishlist_items

  resources :data_feeds
  get '/get_data_feeds', to: 'data_feeds#get_feed_url', as: 'feed_url'

  resources :genders

  resources :trends

  resources :sub_categories

  resources :color_tags

  resources :colors

  resources :categories

  delete '/products/:url', to: 'products#destroy'

  resources :products do
    member do
      get 'buy'
      post 'wish'
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

If the url i'm sending the delete request to is `http://localhost:3000/products/www.test.com` I get the error `No route matches [DELETE] "/products/www.test.com"` if the url I sent the delete request to is `http://localhost:3000/products/:url` I get the error `Couldn't find Product with 'id'=:url`

My Destroy method code:

```
 def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:url])
    @product.destroy
    respond_with(@product, status: 200)
 end
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: No route matches [DELETE] /product/www.test.com

Comment: you are sending to wrong path, change path DELETE '/product/:url', to: 'products#destroy'

Comment: No route matches [DELETE] "/products/www.test.com" -- It appears I am not, I just had a typo in my first comment to Milind

Comment: Please add your entire `routes.rb` file

Comment: @Pak Done, i've added it to the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Rails is considering your URL parameter as the specification of the format of the response. You can override the constraints of the parameter as follows:

```
constraints: { url: /[^\/]+/ }
```

This will make sure that the URL parameter can be anything except for `/`. The whole route should look like this:

```
delete "/products/:url", to: "products#destroy", constraints: { url: /[^\/]+/ }, as: :products_destroy_with_url
```

And use it like this:

```
link_to "Destroy", products_destroy_with_url_path("www.test.com"), method: :delete
```

Comment: Probably the right answer, next time use ``rake routes`` or ``rake routes | grep product`` to check your routes in your console, or better yet write tests for your routes !

Comment: Since Rails 4 (I believe) you can also visit `/info/rails` and try to match your URLs directly in the "tester".

Comment: @JiříPospíšil You are correct, it was a typo in my question. I am still getting the error No route matches [DELETE] "/products/www.test.com" if I make my request to a url of /products/:url I get the error "Couldn't find Product with 'id'=:url"

Comment: @JiříPospíšil thank you, this has fixed my routing error however I now receive the error "Couldn't find Product with 'id'=www.test.com" I know this is technically outside the boundaries of my question however do you have any advice on this? my destroy method is in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @JiříPospíšil Forget what I said, i'm using a Find which is find by id, my mistake, I apologise

Comment: @Grant Yeah, `find_by_url` (and check for nil) should do the trick.